# Invalid property value for margin-left: auto

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry for asking a question that probably has been asked a gazillion times, but I couldnt find an answer. I don't know why the browser gives me an `Invalid property value` for `margin-left: 0 auto` yet somehow a little bit of margin is added to the left (is this a rendering bug?).
It actually works without the `-left` but I have no idea why.

The complete example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/zw7n0h2j/5/

```css
#wrapper {
  width:800px;
}

.figure {
    display: block;
    /* margin: 0; */
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    width: 50%; 
}

.figure img {
    width: 100%;
}

.figure figcaption { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <figure class="figure" >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
        <figcaption>My caption</figcaption>
    </figure> 
</div>
```

Comment: maybe `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I indicated in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-left` cannot have multiple arguments. unlike `margin`. so `margin-left: 0 auto` is invalid as `0` and `auto` are two separate arguments, while `margin: 0 auto` is valid as this is shorthand for

```css
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

These are applied in a clockwise order, so if you do `margin: 12px, 13px, 14px, 15px;` the margins would be applied to the top, right, bottom, and left items respectfully.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Comment: Thank you. I would have assumed `margin: 0 auto` would center vertically too. I guess centering with "margin" is not anymore preferred over flexbox.

Comment: @Marcellvs That is still absolutely possible. Margin-left by design only effects the left margin, so the right margin cannot balance it out by being an equal value. Don’t forget to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can add margin to the left of an element using `margin-left: 10px`.

You can also make use of the shorthand margin property which follows a clockwise order starting from top and going all the way to the left. [margin: top right bottom left]

If you want to apply 10px margin to the left of the element, you can use `margin: 0 0 0 10px`

or, if you want to apply a 10px margin to both right and left of the element using the shorthand margin property, you can use `margin: 0 10px`

For more information, you can refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) on CSS margin properties by MDN.